# Dynamic project-wide variable in Emacs

Tags: variables, emacs, project

I'd like to have a project-wide variable which I can change during looking at that project. In other words, I'd like to get it affected whenever opening a file. Yes, I know `.dir-locals.el` exist in Emacs world. But I think it would be reset to the value set in `.dir-locals.el` whenever opening a file under that project.

Could I get some hints from you, please?

Comment: If you're hoping to be able to `(setq var value)` as normal and have that reflected in all buffers for that 'project' (however you are defining that term), then there is no such thing.  You *could* implement it in Emacs 26+ using `add-variable-watcher` though.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of thing you might want to use a function instead of a variable (directly).  Specifically, use a getter and setter function.

All of your project code can invoke the getter function to get the value (which can be cached in a variable).  And all of your code can invoke the setter function to change the value (which, again, can be cached in a variable).

These functions can be visible globally to your project.  The cache variable would be accessed only by the getter and setter functions.

---

But as for code everywhere in your project *being informed* when the value gets updated and do what's appropriate with the new value whenever that happens, see @Phil's comment about the use of a variable - the same considerations apply.

You can have a hook in the setter function (or advise it), so that it does something additional (e.g. informs interested/subscribed code) whenever it updates the value.

---

For a variable you can do something similar using, as @Phils said in a comment, using `add-variable-watcher`.

For a user-option variable you can do something similar using `:set` and `:get` functions in the `defcustom`.  (But those take effect only if changes are made using appropriate Customize functions or the Customize UI.)

Answer (score 1):

You can `eval` in the `dir-locals.el`  So, if you have a variable `my-var` that you want to be able to change with `setq` you could do something like

```
((nil . ((eval . (or (boundp 'my-var) (setq my-var 'default))))))
```

There are warnings about using `eval` in a dir-local though, since any code could be run there.

Comment: In particular, note that when you `eval` in `.dir-locals.el` it's up to *you* to make sure that you are setting buffer-local values.

Comment: @phils good point, I hadn't considered that. I guess if I changed it to `setq-local` it would require reloading all the project buffers, so there would be a tradeoff.